# AngularJS, ui-router and bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

have some issues with displaying modal window when selected an option

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

app controller

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            $stateProvider
            .state('home',{
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
                controller: 'myCtrl'
        })
    }])
```

home controller

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($http, $scope) {
  $http.get('test.json').success(function (data) {
     $scope.selected = data;
  });
});
```

contacts.html

```
<select ng-model="selectedRegion" data-ng-options="location for location in selected.regions">
    <option value="">Region</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" data-ng-options="place for place in selected.countries[selectedRegion]">
    <option value="">Country</option>
</select>
        {{selectedRegion}}
```

How can I make a modal window, where I can display, for example {{selectedRegion}} after selecting relevant Region or country?
Please help, I tried to inject ['ui.bootstrap'], and ng-click on button works fine. But how to do that with select? Thanks

here is [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PcX7CFBvGP1ruBBah0Lx?p=preview)

Comment: But there's no modal available in demo and demo is broken due to declaring same module twice. Use `ng-change` for what you are asking

Comment: Yes, sorry for broken plunk, missed it. And thanks for help, I tried to make it with ng-click directive and found out that it should ng-change directive applied with select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some work to do, from the plunk you gave.

- Replace `angular.module('myApp', [])` with `angular.module('myApp')` in *home.js*
- Add a `ng-change` on the list of countries.
- On change, we will open a modal

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5esAgxBO7TA9PRkJBbdE?p=preview)**

Added `ui.bootstrap` as a module dependency, for the modal

Comment: Thanks, a lot, and sorry for not working plunk, missed it